# Could Oonoki's Dust release disintegrate the Amaterasu?

Tags: naruto, boruto

The Amaterasu, which is the highest form of fire release (aka [Blaze Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amaterasu)) produces black flames at the focal point of the user, and can't be quenched or destroyed by normal means; even if the user dies, the flames can only be put out if the user wills it to or after it has completely burned its target to smitter.

Oonoki's [Particle style](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dust_Release) on the other hand disintegrates everything within the 3-Dimensional object on a molecular level and converts it to dust. This got me wondering **what would happen if the amaterasu was used against the Dust release.** would the Amaterasu burn the 3 dimensional object which shapes the dust release? or will the Dust release completely disintegrate the "un-extinguishable black flames".

Comment: The Amaterasu also burns anything it comes in contact with, even fire and dimensions. @W.Are what stops the amaterasu from burning out the 3-Dimensional object that the dust release is made of. No exception on the Amaterasu have been also mentioned except the fact that amaterasu can burn "anything". So the answer is not provided actually

Comment: Also, what counts as normal means? i know that sealing the flames is a way of putting Amaterasu out but aside from that no other method of counteracting it have been mentioned, You might wanna check the Amaterasu link, seems you left that one out.

Comment: Ah. I get your point. I actually looked at both links and I missed the one you mentioned about Amaterasu consuming everything. I assumed that normal means include the use of water. I mean, isn't water what you use to normally put out a fire? But then again, including that info you mentioned, wouldn't they just cancel each other out as they both disintegrate anything they come into contact with?

Comment: The amaterasu burns any kinda material even water, flames, tailed beast chakra cloak. Its not like the average Fire release. It can be absorbed using Rinnengan or Sealed into something else. I'm not sure about this but for 2 Jutsu's to cancel out they need to have the same strength and chakra, not sure about that one thou. Nine tails spoke about something like that when he cancellled out 2 to 7 tails tailed beast bomb.

Comment: I think amaterasu burns anything thing it was cast on but it takes some time but the dust release disintegrates anything which is faster, so if you use both jutsu amaterasu will disappear because the object will turn into dust so amaterasu has nothing left to burn hence stops.

Comment: I think amaterasu is actually faster, unlike the dust release, he user does not need to weave any seals, all they need to do  is see their opponent and then cast the black flames at the focal point. Tsichukage howerver needs to use his hands to form the 3D object

Comment: @TheAnimeScientist I am talking about speed of burning of object.

Comment: hmmm what makes you think the speed of burning is slow, don't forget that in sasuke's case, he can use his right eye to fashion the amaterasu into whatever weapon he chooses, remember sasuke vs naruto the final fight, his amaterasu when fashioned into a weapon was more lethal than just random flames @Ch.SivaRamKishore

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think so.

[image]

Here we see two particle styles/dust release colliding. This means that this jutsu just like other jutsu can be interfered with by strong enough jutsu. Examples being Rinnegan absorption and other Particle styles. Meaning that if a jutsu has sufficient energy it can deflect the Particle style, just like when Rasengan and Chidori clash over and over throughout the entire series.

So I propose that the Dust release and Amaterasu will also collide with each other. Amaterasu is an highly destructive and highly powerful technique I think it has sufficient power in it to interfere with the Particle Style and either A) overcome it like it does here.

[image]

Or B) cause a big explosion like every other jutsu collision. Here’s some “new” evidence from Boruto Next Gen.

Sarada’s Fireball and Mitsuki’s lightning is enough to stop a Particle style so yeah, Amatersu should be able to stop it too.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say amaterasu is cast on some object (tailed beast in case of Sasuke, inside of a toad for Itachi) they burn object for few seconds  but the object in question is still intact, but if you use particle style on still burning object the moment it toches the object it disappears into dust (see latest boruto anime) hence amaterasu also disappears.

Comment: The context i meant, was the Amaterasu used against the dust release particle style, and not the dust released used on an object burning with Amaterasu, those are completely different scenarios. The difference is obvious  because Amaterasu burns until nothing (including ash) remains, if the object its burning disintegrates (no longer exists), it will have nothing else to burn and hence won't burn and not cause the particle style necessarily put it out.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin if amaterasu is cast against dust release it just engulfs around it & since it is made of 3 nature transformation it might disrupt the chakra balance hence stops dust release.